# jQuery "Exception thrown and not caught" error in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Alright I've seen this particular problem a couple of times here on SO, but it all didn't solve my case. Here's the website we are talking about: http://kwestievan.nl/unityexpress

Open in IE7/8 and don't mind any CSS errors that might be there.

If I look at the console I see "Exception thrown and not caught" on line 1011 of jquery.js (1.6.2). I take it that this has nothing to do with jQuery but with my own code, but I have no clue where to start. I might do something wrong in my code but the console doesn't give a hint at all. All other browsers don't have a problem with the code as it is now.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Do you have any `throw/catch` statements in your code?

Comment: I am not receiving the error in IE8.  If you hit F12 in ie8 it gives you a debug console similar to firebug.

Comment: @kmb385 that's interesting. Do the navigation, carousel at the top and language switcher work then too? Or does it still give errors of some sort?

Comment: @Alex well not in my own code. However, since it is a WordPress backend with several plugins that also use JS, there are some try catch statements. But I doubt that they are causing this...

Comment: @Alex I have try and finally in my code and facing similar issue

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, seeing an "Exception thrown and not caught" error in IE8 (while in IE7 mode) using jQuery 1.6.4.

The stack trace started in the `finally` clause in jQuery's resolveWith() and went through ready() and doScrollCheck() **only**, but the problem was in my code, executed via $.ready().

I found the problem in my code, which was actually an "Object does not support this property or method" error, only by commenting out code until I could find the offending line, and then running that line in the console.

I think that the `try {} finally {}` block in jQuery's resolveWith() may have been masking the source of the error. I'm not sure, but if I had to debug it again I might try:

- moving my code outside of $.ready(); or
- in a local copy of jQuery, adding a `catch (e){}` clause in resolveWith() to inspect the error

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same error with jQuery UI tabs in IE only(version 8). As it turns out, I had invalid HTML on which FF and Chrome gave me a pass. Not so with IE.

I discovered this by running the HTML validator which pointed to an HTML error (I had an extra quote on a DIV id). I fixed this error and the js error message went away in IE.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable JavaScript debugging in your "Internet Options." or in your developer tools for IE.  The code should "break" on the line that is giving you problems, and then you can inspect the call stack to see which of your code triggered the problem.

Comment: I am already using the developer tools (F12) and I look at the Script tab and then on the right side "Console". I see the tab "Call Stack", but the list is empty. So nothing is to be done there. Am I in the wrong spot?

Comment: The call stack is usually populated when the code breaks.  Debugging has to be enabled.

Comment: Yes I did that, thanks. But the stack traces back to the ready() event that fires when dom is loaded and jQuery can begin. So no call from my end, or so it seems. I do use the `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {} );` trick to be able to use `$` while in noConflict mode. Could this be causing IE to throw up?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips. I solved this by removing the ":nth-of-type()" jQuery selector which seemed to choke IE8.